# MySQL (Percona) fails to start after moving databases

Tags: mysql, percona

I ran out of disk space for MySQL. So I stopped mysql (service mysql stop), moved the files from /var/lib/mysql to a temp dir, mounted a larger disk at /var/lib/mysql put all the files back from the original mysql dir and tried to restart mysql (Service mysql start) and it give me the:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
Failed!
```

I read that after doing that it would just start back up like nothing happend. What happened?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on **dba.stackexchange.com**.

Comment: Thanks I will post it over there.